# How to get jenkins to build all other projects

Tags: java, jenkins

I have an application named core which is used by a few of my other applications. I am trying to configure Jenkins so that, when core is built it forces all other applications to build.

This would be a post build action only when successfully built but I don't see any option for performing this?

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Post-build Actions section --> Build other projects.

Comment: perfect - thanks - was looking in the post build steps which was slightly different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project configuration go to `post-build actions > projects` to build: 
[image: http://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/a3a903b0027c9799889c3c7aa806b5ef.png]
<sub>(source: [scaleengine.net](http://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/a3a903b0027c9799889c3c7aa806b5ef.png))</sub>

Another option is in the `build triggers` section:
[image: http://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/72e02f54de8e105071305e145125b70c.png]
<sub>(source: [scaleengine.net](http://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/72e02f54de8e105071305e145125b70c.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can use any build tool like ANT to control your build and schedule a single jenkins job to run it,

OR

1. You Create every build as a single job (JobA=BuildCore, JobB=BuildAppB, JobX=BuildX...)
2. Use [build flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) (Useful sample of usage inside the link)
3. Create a build flow controller job, and manage all the sequence